# Get default response via NEST?

Tags: nest

When you navigate directly to your Elastic Search cluster's root URL, you're presented with a system summary like this:

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Ultra-Marine",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.19.0",
    "snapshot_build" : false
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Is there a way to get this response via an instance of NEST.ElasticClient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve this information by calling `client.RootNodeInfo()`.